# Codeigniter remove index.php on Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) server

Tags: codeigniter

I have one issue I am using one .htaccess file form one year this code is working on all server but today I have one new server same code is not working. I am not able to remove index.php from URL. My server is Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat).
My code for .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Cache-Control:  "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
</IfModule>
```

In config file I set below settings

$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

This same code is working on another server

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this: (but i'm not sure)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I'm using Apache, too. My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

Comment: Yes In folder my path is http://appdev.triz.co.in/ssetschool_portal/admin If I use http://appdev.triz.co.in/ssetschool_portal/index.php/admin url then it is working

Answer (score 0):

1. load the "mod_rewrite.so" in http.conf;
2. replace AllowOverride "None" with "All"
3. try those code in .htaccess:
   [image]

Comment: Sorry I can not understand first and second step

Comment: step1 means you must open your rewrite module before using it. Just edit the apache configuration file - "http.conf", and remove the "#" before this line - "LoadModule rewrite_module module/mod_rewrite.so", and restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have mode_rewrite enabled from apache, debian server you can run `a2enmod rewrite`
2. Try the following htaccess, it worked for me when I encountered same problem

Htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Goodluck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I hope this will help you.